# Chrome 68 player behaviour

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

In latest update of chrome (68.0.3440.106), the native video player has endless loading indicator if the video tag have preload="none".

How can i fix this?

[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PN5T.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, Fixed this issue below.

`<video src="./foo.mp4" />`

to

`<video><source src="./foo.mp4"/></video>`